# Copy files based on a timestamp value in a file name

Tags: regex, string, bash

All the files reside in one folder. File names look like following:

```
1695_6892_20160321000000_20160321235959.file.name.csv.gz
```

The third substring (after the second `_`) is a timestamp.

How do i copy all files with a `timestamp < 20150531000000` to another folder `my_folder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in *.gz; do test `echo $i | cut -d _ -f 3` -lt 20150531000000 && cp $i my_folder; done
```

Comment: Upvote for not using `ls` and instead properly using a shell wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

And... You can use awk.

```
for i in $(ls -1 org_folder | awk -F"_" '{ if ($3 < 20150531000000) print $0 }'); cp mv org_foler/$i my_folder/; done
```

Comment: just a fyi: ls does not need the -1 except when you are looking at it.  ls knows when it is not being displayed and does not format in columns

Comment: @tomc @han056 Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: 
                `for file in *.txt`. Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score -1):

`ls | awk -F'_' '$3<20150531000000{print}'`

should be the files you want to move, so

`for f in "$(ls|awk -F'_' '$3<20150531000000{print}')"; do mv "${f}" elsewhere/ ;done`